# Edit Text Background Resource

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my activity is one EditText, one Toggle Button and one Test Button. If my ToggleButton Pressed Edit Text Backgroud set in Red Style (red.xml), and when not pressed set in Green Stlye (green.xml). But when I press Test Button alredy Write me Red :'(

Please Help me!!

My Code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

ToggleButton Toggle;
EditText ettext;
Button test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toggle=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbkapcsolo);
    Toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    ettext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etszovegmezo);

    test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMent);
    test.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        ettext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);

    }else ettext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Drawable style=ettext.getBackground();
    Drawable green=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green);


    if(style==green){
        Toast.makeText(this,"GREEN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"RED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}
Thank you for help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned onClickListner to Button as well. What ever code you have in onClickListner wil be executed. Remove onClickListner from button or write some code for button.

Hope this will help you

Comment: On Click Program Show me in popup "RED" or "GREEN"

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the Toggle and the onCheckedChanged() method.
Try setting your Toggle to true or false before you set the onCheckdChangedListener.

You can do this in the xml if you do android:checked="true" like this:

```
<Switch 
   android:id="@+id/switchid"
   android:checked="true"/>
```

Comment: The program is checking Background color, but when the background is green and I click on test button not Show me "Green".... it show me RED